# How to find a webpage in FTP directory?

Tags: html, url, ftp, directory

I am looking for one specific web page in my large directory of files. Problem is I have no idea what to search. I have the pages URL and I have found the page extensions of the file, but not the page itself. How can I find this page?

The page is: http://napaautocaremarketing.com/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your question is way too broad and you don't demonstrate the slightest understanding of the problem and you did not even mention which tools you are using. Unfortunately, stack overflow is not for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your FTP client, we can't just tell you the magic answer due to this, but most of the time, you should try graphically to find the `search` menu, and search inside your file content for this for instance:

```
<a href="http://store.napaautocaremarketing.com/napa/UserContentStart.aspx?Category=32" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();"
```

Otherwise, you should download every files, and use a dedicated searching software to do so. Or use this command:

```
grep '<a href="http://store.napaautocaremarketing.com/napa/UserContentStart.aspx?Category=32" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();"' *.html
```

Comment: I am using FileZilla and forgive me for being a newb but I typically don't deal with large site files in FTP (All my sites in the past have been 5-15 pages.) How would I go about searching w/ FileZilla? Server>Search Remote Files...?

Comment: You can try `View` -> `Filename Filters`, but I doubt that you can find anything with this client. I strongly advise you to download everything and use your default searching client to find the correct location ;)